# ReportLab rows with different columns

Tags: python, pdf, reportlab

I am writing my data in a pdf table. It looks like this: `[[1,2,3,4], [1,2], [1,2,3,4], [1,2,3]]` -- the rows have different lengths, ranging from 2 to 4, as you can see.

I'm using this code to style the rows:

```py
table.setStyle(TableStyle([
    ('INNERGRID', (0,0), (-1,-1), 0.25, colors.black),
    ('BOX', (0,0), (-1,-1), 0.25, colors.grey),
]))
```

However this generates 4 columns for each row. How can I ensure that I only get the number of columns corresponding to my row length?

Comment: @Andy Kubiak `code` data = [[0, 1, 2, 3],
        [0, 1],
        [0, 1, 2, 3],
        [0, 1, 2]]
gridlines = [('GRID', (i, 0), (i, len(j)), colors.grey) for i, j in enumerate(data)]

print gridlines
style = TableStyle(gridlines)
s = getSampleStyleSheet()
s = s["BodyText"]
t=Table(data)
t.setStyle(style)    This is my code and i am getting exception in  t.setstyle

Answer (score 0):

Explicitly draw only the borders you need. Look up "TableStyle Line Commands" in the [documentation](http://www.reportlab.com/docs/reportlab-userguide.pdf).

**Edit:**

Assuming your data list looks like:

```
data = [[0, 1, 2, 3],
        [0, 1],
        [0, 1, 2, 3],
        [0, 1, 2]]
```

then maybe something like this would work:

```
>>> lineweight = 0.25
>>> gridlines = [('GRID', (i, 0), (i, len(j)), lineweight, colors.grey) for i, j in enumerate(data)]
>>> gridlines
[('GRID', (0, 0), (0, 4), 0.25, colors.grey),
 ('GRID', (1, 0), (1, 2), 0.25, colors.grey),
 ('GRID', (2, 0), (2, 4), 0.25, colors.grey),
 ('GRID', (3, 0), (3, 3), 0.25, colors.grey)]
```

Hope that helps.

*edit2:* adds `lineweight`

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13812603/reportlab-table-with-a-column-spanning-all-rows-split-across-pdf-page  .i have gone through this solution as well but i am not able to understand how to create columns dynamically.

Comment: data = [[0, 1, 2, 3],
        [0, 1],
        [0, 1, 2, 3],
        [0, 1, 2]]
gridlines = [('GRID', (i, 0), (i, len(j)), colors.grey) for i, j in enumerate(data)]

print gridlines
style = TableStyle(gridlines)
s = getSampleStyleSheet()
s = s["BodyText"]
t=Table(data)
t.setStyle(style)

Comment: it is raising  error if len(cmd)<5: raise ValueError('bad line command '+ascii(cmd))

Comment: Woops, sorry, missed the line weight. I'll edit my solution snippet.

Comment: I have tried running.we are not able eliminate the columns from the above code :).

Comment: Can you be more specific?

Comment: i don't know how to attach an image otherwise i would have attached the output pdf.Run the code you are not getting the appropriate output.

Comment: i have posted my question here. https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/reportlab-users/qifa4PsHnDw